# Formula to calculate historical data based off a specific condition?

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to observe historical trends on customer acquisitions (new and returning) and am looking to use a formula to automate it for me.

Essentially, I am looking to determine the average amount of new customers we acquire on a specific day, specific week, and specific month. For example: what are the average customers we have acquired every Monday for the past 6 months, or what is the average number of customers we acquire the first week of every month?

[image: Column F, I, and L would be the averages I calculate. Column A and B are the days of the week/date those numbers fall on.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution:

You can use the date operators in your `QUERY` statement to filter by month, week, or even day of week.

**Examples:**

every Monday for past 6 months

`=query(A1:B, "select avg(B) where datediff(todate(now()),todate(A)) < 180 and dayofweek(A) = 2", 1)`

**first week of every month**

`=query(A1:B, "select month(A),avg(B) where day(A) <= 7 group by month(A) offset 1", 1)`

You would need to tweak the sample queries to cover your data range and which columns do you need to average and compare.

### References:

[QUERY()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)

[Query Language Reference | Scalar Functions](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#scalar-functions)